# menu.findItem(R.id.*) is null- Android

Tags: android, menuitem

I am trying to enable/disable a refresh button when certain things happen in my app, but I get a null pointer exception that I can't figure out. I am setting a boolean `addingRefresh` or `removingRefresh` to true depending on the situation and then calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to enable or disable the button, however the menu item is returned null. I have searched the internet for why this may be but can't find anything.

Code for `onCreateOptionsMenu()` (called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is called)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (addingRefresh) {
        //below line as well as other similar line cause exceptions
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(true);
        addingRefresh = false;
    } else if (removingRefresh) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setEnabled(false);
        removingRefresh = false;
    } else if (addingLoading) {

    }
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: onPrepareOptionsMenu() is called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is called; onCreateOptionsMenu() is only called once.

Comment: Also, you are inflating the menu after you are trying to find the item.  That can't be good.  One second, and I'll post a more thorough answer.

Comment: It did run that line of code at the correct time in onCreateOptionsMene(), so it must have been called somehow...
I will try using onPrepareOptionsMenu() 
thanks!

Comment: Just a hint: inflate first, then do the manipulation. You got `NullPointerException` because there is no item in the menu when you call `menu.findItem()`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is some cleaned up code for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
private MenuItem mMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh)
    return true;
}

private void setMenuItemEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mMenuItem.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Just for clearing the doubt.
You should use

```
menu.findItem(R.id.menuId);
```

after inflating the menu

Answer (score 0):

for me cause of issue was wrong import:
android.widget.SearchView

instead
androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

and take care about namespaces
app:actionViewClass